# Share session within different domains

Tags: magento2, session

I have one website, one store and multiple store views. One store view has different domain. I want this store view to have the same session, if product is added in one store view, should be also added in store view that has different domain. How can i achieve this? I can't use SID param in Url, because SidResolver is deprecated. I tried setting PHPSESSID cookie but this doesn't work. Magento v 2.4